# A new coefficient of correlation

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, asymptotics

I am new to probability and asymptotic distributions in general. Please forgive my ignorance because I do not have much experience about the content. There is a new coefficient of correlation presented in this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2020.1758115) and they claim it's asymptotic distribution without proof. I tried using the Delta method but I am confused what $g(\cdot)$ to use.

More specifically, suppose $(X,Y)$ have no ties which can be rearrange as $(X_{(1)}, Y_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}, Y_{(n)} )$ and the rank: $r(Y_{X(i)}) = \sum_{j=1}^n 1 \{ Y_{(j)} \le Y_{X(i)}\}$, the coefficient of correlation is defined as:

$$ \xi_n (X, Y): = 1- \frac{3 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_{i+1} -r_i}{n^2 -1}$$
which is asymptotically normal under independence with
$$ \sqrt{n} \xi_n (X, Y) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, 2/5)$$

Comment: For those who can't access the gated version of the paper, the preprint is at https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.10140

Comment: the author clearly states that the asymptotic normality is a restatement of a theorem from the paper ([6]). Since that result is a 'main theorem' of that work, I doubt that the result is going to follow easily, and the best thing to do would be to try to understand the result in [6]

Comment: That paper is hard to find. Do you have a copy of it?

Comment: The notation in the above presented question is not clear or consistent. For example it eventually uses $r_i$ but defines something not quite the same called $r(Y_{X(i)})$. Also I wonder if $X_{i}$ is intended to be a positive integer in the set $\{1, ..., n\}$? It is also not clear how $(X,Y)$ relates to $(X_{(1)}, Y_{(1)}, ..., X_{(n)}, Y_{(n)})$ and what "no ties" means.

Comment: Refer to the paper's link provided by Michael Lugo.